# Не добавляются уникальные элементы в массив

Tags: javascript, массивы

Пишу свой велосипед по удалению одинаковых элементов массива. Как бы при выводе в консоль дубли не попадаются т.е выводится всё как нужно (1, 11, 2, 4, 5, 3). Но при этом в результирующий массив res ничего не попадает. Помогите исправить

```
var res = [];
var a = [1, 1, 11, 2, 4, 2, 5, 3, 1];
var N = a.length;
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
   f = 1;
   for (j = 0; j < N; j++) 
      if (a[i] == a[j] && i != j) {
         f = 0;
         break;
      }
      if (f == 1){ 
         console.log(a[i]); //в консоле(1,11,2,4,5,3)
         res.push(a[i]) // в итоговом массиве 1,1,11,2,4,2,5,3,1 -----что не верно
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: второй if надо просто вынести из внутреннего цикла for

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Честно говоря не хочу смотреть ваш велосипед. Да он и в консоль выводит дубли. Не знаю как вы проверяли.

Но, кмк, проще сделать так:

```js
var arr = [1, 1, 11, 2, 4, 2, 5, 3, 1];
var set = new Set(arr);
arr = Array.from(set);

console.log(arr);
```

Объекты [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) позволяют сохранять уникальные значения любого типа, как примитивы, так и другие типы объектов. (вроде браузеры поддерживают)

[Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) создаёт новый экземпляр Array из массивоподобного или итерируемого объекта.

Comment: Неплохо, для меня познавательно )

Answer (score 2):

Получение уникальных элементов через [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
var arr = [1, 1, 11, 2, 4, 2, 5, 3, 1];
arr = arr.filter(function(itm, i, a) {
  return i === a.indexOf(itm);
});

console.log(arr);
```

Отлично поддерживается браузерами (IE9+) в отличие от красивого и современного способа [@АлексейШиманский](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/611753/220571), который, к сожалению, не работает даже в IE11 (из-за `Array.from`), если поддержка IE важна.

---

Если поддержка IE не важна или используется Babel, то можно сделать то же самое через arrow function:

```js
var arr = [1, 1, 11, 2, 4, 2, 5, 3, 1];
arr = arr.filter((itm, i, a) => i === a.indexOf(itm));

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Обычно код через Babel прогоняют, так что `Array.from()` - не проблема.

Comment: Ну это кто как. В любом случае, если ещё сделать через arrow function,    то код будет не сильно отличаться по лаконичности от принятого ответа.

Answer (score 1):

**Update 3**: Предлагаю вам такое решение:

```js
$(function() {
  var a = [1, 1, 11, 2, 4, 2, 5, 3, 1];
  var b = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
    var status = 1;
    for(var j = 0; j < b.length; j++){
      if(a[i] == b[j]){
        status = 0;
      };
    };
    if(status == 1){
      b[b.length] = a[i];
    };
  };
  console.log(a);
  console.log(b);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: А что сделать если нужно не удалять элементы в старом массиве а вставлять их в новый?можете написать?

Comment: @J.Joe, держите

Comment: ,не много другое,  должно получиться массив 1, 11, 2, 4, 5, 3 и вот чёт я туплю:(

Comment: @J.Joe, вы это имели введу?

Comment: @J.Joe, смотрите, я обновил ответ. Почему бы вам изначально не копировать массив и из второго не вычитать?

Comment: я хз как правильно,прост я хотел по старинке без Array.from  т.е реализовать саму идею т.е мне не понятно что например если я делаю условие a[i]!=a[j] во вложеном цикле то добавляются куча дублей а если вынести добавление вне второго цикла то ничего не получается

Comment: @J.Joe, смотрите, ещё раз переделал. Сейчас так?

Comment: да,спасибо вам.